# Disable a standard systemd service in Yocto build

Tags: yocto, systemd

I need to start my own `systemd` service, let's call it `custom.service`. I know how to write a recipe for it to be added and enabled on boot:

```
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "custom.service"
SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_${PN} = "enable"
```

However, it conflicts with one of the default `systemd` services - `systemd-timesyncd.service`.

Is there a nice preferred way to disable that default `systemd` service in my bitbake file even though the `systemd_XX.bb` actually enables it?

I can create a `systemd_%.bbappend` file to modify the `systemd` settings, but I can't locate the place where one service can be disabled leaving all others enabled.

---

The working solution I found is to remove the `timesyncd` altogether using

```
PACKAGECONFIG_remove = "timesyncd"
```

But I wonder if this is a appropriate way and if there is a way to just disable it, but leave in the system.

Comment: Did you write the `PACKAGECONFIG:remove = "timesyncd"` in a `.../recipes-core/systemd/systemd_%.bbappend` or in another file? This doesn't seem to have any effect for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the system runs fine with the other package removed, then removing the package *is* a preferred solution. Fewer packages means a simpler system.

Answer (score 12):

How about adding a .bbappend recipe for the conflicting service you want disabled. In it, you would add:
`SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_${PN} = "disable"`

Comment: This works but for the new bitbake you need to use like this: `SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE:${PN} = "disable"`

Answer (score 3):

Usually you would set SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_${PN} = "disable" and that would let the service be part of image but disabled on boot. However for systemd which provides a lot of default service units this may not be a solution you might want to deploy. You could surgically delete the symlink in etc which will ensure that service is not started automatically on boot but the .service file is still part of image. So add following to systemd_%.bbappend file in your layer

```
do_install_append() {
        rm -rf ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-timesyncd.service
}
```

There are other ways to disable this e.g. using systemd presets as described [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use the **systemd.preset — Service enablement presets** and in particular following steps.

- Create a `.bbappend` file `meta-xxx/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_%.bbappend` with this content:

```
do_configure_append() {
    #disabling autostart of systemd-timesyncd
    sed -i -e "s/enable systemd-timesyncd.service/disable systemd-timesyncd.service/g" ${S}/presets/90-systemd.preset
}
```

In my yocto-based Linux distribution (yocto zeus release) above steps are enough to disable the service which remains installed.
In the output distribution previous steps modify the file `/lib/systemd/system-preset/90-systemd.preset`.
After the modification, in that file, appear the row: `disable systemd-timesyncd.service` and this row substitutes the raw: `enable systemd-timesyncd.service`

At [this link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) there are some information about the topic: **systemd.preset — Service enablement presets**.

Other [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67460881/).

---

I was not able to use `SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_${PN} = "disable"` in this context.
For other recipes (for example `dnsmasq_2.82.bb`) the previous assignment works correctly and I have used it to enable (or disable) a service in the yocto distribution.

Answer (score -2):

I think the "official" way to do this is to have something like this somewhere in your project:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-systemd = "--disable-timesyncd"
```

This does basically the same you already suggested. To simply not enable the service you have to do it manually since you can modify the auto enable only per recipe.

Comment: Sorry @Caspar, I've tried this and the service was still there running.

Comment: WARNING: systemd-1_230+gitAUTOINC+3a74d4fc90-r0 do_configure: QA Issue: systemd: invalid PACKAGECONFIG: --disable-timesyncd [invalid-packageconfig]