# Disable systemD services at compile time

Tags: embedded, yocto, systemd

I have looked at this question: [Disable a standard systemd service in Yocto build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651371/disable-a-standard-systemd-service-in-yocto-build) and am trying to implement the solution with the systemd_%.bbappend file, but it doesn't appear to be working.  I am trying to remove (preferred) or at least disable two services, the NTP service and the Getty service.  I am running Yocto (Pyro) on a 4.14.16 kernel with an i.MX6 target.

I have been putting the file in *poky/meta-markem-imaje-bsp/recipes-core/systemd/*.  Does it need to be somewhere else?

This is the contents of my file:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Customization of systemD services."

do_install_append() {
    rm ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
}

PACKAGECONFIG_remove = "timesyncd"

FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/systemd/system"

REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES= "systemd"
```

Update - I fixed the bb_append to be just bbappend, and it no longer compiles.  I am seeing this:

Update 2 - The file is working.  For some reason, putting getty in the PACKAGECONFIG_remove didn't work, but the deletion of the link worked to disable the service (once I fixed the rm command).  I have updated the bbappend file above with the final version.  Thanks all.

Keep in mind that I am a Yocto noob.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you: do you want to disable those two services or remove packages from the image completely?

Comment: Either is fine.  Removing is preferred, but if it is easier to just disable them I fine with that; I am not in a bind for rootFS space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a look into systemd_232.bb and systemd.inc on the pyro branch it looks like the first .patch file in your SRC_URI failes to apply with "missing file".

I think this is because you overwrite S with ${WORKDIR} but in systemd.inc it is set to "${WORKDIR}/git". So the git repository of systemd is cloned to ${WORKDIR}/git and you try to patch it in ${WORKDIR}.

Remove S=${WORKDIR} from your .bbappend file should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Its `.bbappend`, not `.bb_append`. Maybe thats already enough. You can check if your append gets applied if it shows in `bitbake-layers show-appends`. If it is listed there, you can inspect its effects with `bitbake -e systemd | less`. With the invocation of less being optional, but convenient :)

Comment: that was at least part of the problem.  I have updated the post; it no longer compiles.