# How disable the RNGD service from Yocto?

Tags: yocto, systemd

Background: I am running Yocto Zeus, and Linux Kernel 4.14 using SystemD.  My target is an embedded i.MX6.

I have been attempting to disable the RNGD service at startup.  It consumes all the cores for many seconds after bootup, and when I manually disable (via **systemctl disable rngd** it is actually disabled and there are no ill-effects (our software doesn't use /dev/random).

I have looked through [Disable a standard systemd service in Yocto build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651371/disable-a-standard-systemd-service-in-yocto-build?noredirect=1&lq=1) and have tried both the package remove and deleting the link, and neither seem to work.  Here are the contents of my *systemd_%.bbappend* file in my layer.

```
# To remove the package completely, add it to this space separated list.
# Not all services can be removed.
PACKAGECONFIG_remove = "timesyncd kmod rngd"

do_install_append() {
    rmdir ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/network
    ln -sfn /var/local/etc/systemd/network ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/network

    rm -f ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rngd.service
}
```

Is there a way to delete this service?  Even with both of those, I still see rngd running at boot.  I am reasonably confident my changes are being included, I can see them if I run **bitbake -e systemd | grep rngd**:

```
gen-ccm-root@ubuntu:~/workdir/tools/poky/build-dev$ bitbake -e systemd | grep rngd
#     "timesyncd kmod rngd"
    rm -f /home/gen-ccm-root/workdir/tools/poky/build-dev/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/systemd/1_243+AUTOINC+efb536d0cb-r0/image/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rngd.service
```

I have also confirmed that the other things in that file are actually taking effect.  The network link is being properly made and I have confirmed that the `timesyncd` service is removed.  I have confirmed that the file I am removing is the link that systemctl disable would remove:

```
~# systemctl disable rngd
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rngd.service.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Poky (Warrior branch) I have a bbappend to disable `rng`. The filename is `rng-tools_%.bbappend` and contains:

```
SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_rng-tools = "disable"
```

Comment: This doesn't get rid of the binaries (not a problem for me), but this solution still works fine in Zeus. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think rngd is provided by systemd? Try removing the `rng-tools` package from your image instead.

I would start by ensuring that rng-tools actually is in the image currently -- you could check the image manifest file to do that.
To remove rng-tools you can modify the actual image recipe so that it does not add rng-tools in the first place or you could try e.g. `IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = " rng-tools"` in your user configuration.

Comment: I just tried replacing rngd in the PACKAGECONFIG_remove with rng-tools, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Sure, because you are changing the configuration of an unrelated package (systemd)... I'll modify the answer to give a potential example fix.

Comment: I changed it as you described, the `IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = "rng-tools rng-tools-dev"` is now in my image recipe, but it is still running at startup.  I also added the `rng-tools-dev` because that showed up in the manifest file as well.

I ran a `bitbake -e rng-tools` and got a dot file to try to find out why it is being included, but to be perfectly honest, I am not entirely sure how to read it.  I will try to attach it to the question.

Comment: The dot file is at https://drive.google.com/file/d/18mXDnzK4vMdByJB4C9vRgyRfjnwjBXhw/view?usp=sharing
rng-tools appears in that file quite a lot, which is surprising because the only Yocto recipe that calls out rng-tools is openssh, which is a RRECOMMENDS dependency.  I don't see any hits in libgcrypto or anything else if I grep for it in my yocto directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a `Variscite's iMX6 SOM` with `sysvinit`.

The `IMAGE_INSTALL_` remove option mentioned didn't work for me, as well as it didn't help removing `rng-tools` from `MACHINE_EXTRA_RDEPENDS`.

I ended up removing the 'recommendation' made by OpenSSH package by doing:

```
BAD_RECOMMENDATIONS = "rng-tools rng-tools-dev"
```