# How to remove getty@tty1 link in yocto dunfell branch at time of compiliation

Tags: yocto, raspberry-pi4

I am building linux system for raspberrypi4 but for some reason I need to remove getty@tty1 service in yocto.

I have created systemd_%.bbappend file for that.

Host PC is Ubuntu 18.04

this is working with warrior branch

Now, I am trying to compile with dunfell branch in yocto

but at the time of systemd compiling it gives an error like

"cannot remove /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1, no such file or deirectory

But at the end, In final image there I can see getty@tty1.service

Also I can't find any other receipe that creates this link.

systemd_%.bbappend looks like this

```
 DESCRIPTION = "Customization of systemD services."

 do_install_append() {

 rm ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service

 }

 FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/systemd/system"

 REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES= "systemd"
```

Thanks

Margish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On more recent versions of systemd (like the one in Yocto dunfell), the links to services are not created by the build system (ninja), but instead by running `systemctl preset-all` on the running system after installation (see [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/db9c5ae73e23d816e2df2a3e10a9a2a60b5b3ed7/NEWS#L939)). This command [reads the systemd preset files](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) to determine which units to enable or disable by default.

In Yocto, what this means is that instead of the links being created as part of the systemd recipe, `systemctl preset-all` is run as part of the `IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND` during image creation in `image.bbclass` (see [here](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/classes/image.bbclass?h=dunfell#n668)). This is why the old method of deleting the symbolic links in `/etc/systemd/system` from the systemd recipe no longer works.

Instead, what you need to do is modify the `90-systemd.preset` file to disable the `getty@tty1` preset (or any other default system service) by changing the below line:

```
enable getty@.service
```

to this:

```
disable getty@.service
```

You can accomplish this using a `bbappend` file as follows<sup>*</sup>:

```
# systemd_%.bbappend
do_install_append() {
    # Disable getty@tty1 from starting at boot time.
    sed -i -e "s/enable getty@.service/disable getty@.service/g" ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system-preset/90-systemd.preset
}
```

<sup>*https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505478/286701</sup>

Comment: am using yocto release Nanbield and `do_install` append syntax was changed. You should use `do_install:append()` instead of.